# Creating efficient, fast, incremental InfluxDB database backups

Tags: database, backup, influxdb

I have a raspberrypi (4b) running Raspbian Linux, collecting IoT data around the house and feeding this into an InfluxDB 1.8.3 (opensource) database. This works fine so far.

I also have a backup which runs daily like this:

```
influxd backup -portable /home/pi/influx-backup/
```

**Question**:

1. This backup process takes almost 30 minutes, during which InfluxDB is almost unuseable, system load climbs to >7 and my Pi cannot collect data. Each backup is a complete backup. Can I somehow create a faster incremental backup daily? The documentation only mentions a `-since` parameter but you'd have to specify this manually, which would be risky.
2. Alternatively, the whole system is backed up daily using `borgbackup` anyway. Stopping Influx, making a `rsync` copy of `/var/lib/influxdb/data` as backup, and restarting it is much, much faster than `influxd backup`. Is this a good alternative idea to backup the database?
3. What other alternatives exist to perform regular, quick, (if possible online) backups of Influx databases?

Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this issue, I have the similar use case to take incremental backup of influxdb V2. Was not able to get the command  from official docs to take backup based on timestamp

Comment: I stuck with rsync once a night, stopping InfluxDB for half a minute, running rsync, then restarting it. Borgbackup also backs up the database but since it's online then, it may be inconsistent, so I use rsync in addition as a "plan B".
Everything else, including the supposedly existing incremental backup, was slower or so obscure I didn't know how to restore cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to this site:

> InfluxDB also has support for incremental backups. Snapshotting from the server now creates a full backup if one does not exist and creates numbered incremental backups after that.

[DataSource](https://influxdbcom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/docs/v0.9/administration/backup_and_restore/)

If this is the case, but you are still having a problem, perhaps you could downsize your data by running continuous queries and a data retention policy.

Comment: I was looking into incremental backups, but the link to the readthedocs.io 'DataSource' you provided is now obsolete.

Comment: This is the current link.
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/process-data/common-tasks/downsample-data/

Comment: @Portfedh That has nothing to do with incremetal backups.